# angular schema form render select box with empty option: value="?"

Tags: angularjs, forms, schema, angular-schema-form

i am using angular schema for to render forms.
I created my own oneOf function that takes a JSON with a few sachems and render the select box for them to choose.
the select box have options, every option choose another schema.
the select box render correctly but i always get the first option empty with value="?".
what should i do to render the select box without the empty option?

6/4/2016:
I tried to create an add on that will create a select box that will choose the first option but with no luck:

```
<div class="form-group {{form.htmlClass}} schema-form-select"
     ng-class="{'has-error': form.disableErrorState !== true && hasError(), 'has-success': form.disableSuccessState !== true && hasSuccess(), 'has-feedback': form.feedback !== false}">
  <label class="control-label {{form.labelHtmlClass}}" ng-show="showTitle()">
    {{form.title}}
  </label>
  <select 
          ng-model="$$value$$"
          ng-model-options="form.ngModelOptions"
          ng-disabled="form.readonly"
          sf-changed="form"
          class="form-control"
          ng-class="form.fieldHtmlClass"
          schema-validate="form"
          ng-options="item.value as item.name group by item.group for item in form.titleMap"
          name="{{form.key.slice(-1)[0]}}"
          ng-init="$$value$$ = form.titleMap[0]">
          <!--<option value="">{{form.defaultText}}</option>-->
  </select>
  <div class="help-block" sf-message="form.description"></div>
</div>
```

this add on by the way is the same like the select from angular schema form, but i added  this :

```
<!--<option value="">{{form.defaultText}}</option>-->
```

for default option text until i will solve this issue.
what do you think i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The empty option is there because your model's default value does not correspond to any of the select options.

To get rid of it, initialize your model to a valie default value from your controller:

```
$scope.foo = $scope.fooOptions[0];
```

You can also use the `ng-init` directive:

```
<select
ng-model="foo"
ng-options="option for option in fooOptions"
ng-init="foo=fooOptions[0]"></select>
```

Comment: but the option is an object not a string, its this {name:'mmm',...}.

Comment: i tried to create an add on that will do that and inside i tried to do what you said: ng-init="$$value$$ = form.titleMap[0]". but with no luck it always blank even when i choose different option.